# Are the programs included in the Web Platform Installer all free?

Tags: .net, iis, web-platform-installer

Are the programs included in the Web Platform Installer all free?

I was under the impression that it was all open-source, free software. But it looks like at least nService isn't: http://www.avensoft.com/nservice.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The criteria for web applications to be included in the Web PI are [located on the IIS website.](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/605/windows-web-application-gallery-principles/)

From this, being free of charge is one of the criteria.

Looking at the nService website it appears that it may be free for 1 'technician' and chargeable after that (didn't read the full licence agreement so could be wrong!)